# Copy list of files to folders depending on name with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Given a directory `dir1` with a list of pdf files and a directory `dir2` with a list of folders, I would like to copy the files into the folders by the following principle: whenever a filename contains a foldername the file is copied into that folder. This is what I tried, but it doesn't work. I believe the reason is that I treat folders like files, but I'm not sure..

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

$FileType = "*.pdf"
$filelist = Get-ChildItem -path "[dir1]" -Filter $FileType
$folderlist = Get-ChildItem -path "[dir2]"


ForEach($file in $filelist)
{
    $file
    $key1 = $file.BaseName
    $key1
    ForEach($folder in $folderlist)
    {
        $folder 
        $key2 = $folder.BaseName
        $key2
        if ($key1 -like $key2){
            Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $folder.FullName
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-like` operator uses wildcards, and will perform a full-length comparison:

```
"a" -like "a" # true
"ab" -like "a" # false
```

So if you want to test if one value **contains** another value, you have to put asterisks at the start and end of the wildcard string:

```
if ($key1 -like "*$key2*")
```

Answer (score 1):

To just get directories, use `-Attributes Directory`

You might use [member enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/#member-enumeration) (`$folderlist.Basename`) and simplify your script to:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

$FileType = "*.pdf"
$filelist = Get-ChildItem -path "$dir1" -Filter $FileType
$folderlist = Get-ChildItem -path "$dir2" -Attributes Directory


ForEach($file in $filelist) {
    $BaseName = $file.BaseName
    if ($folderlist.Basename -Contains $BaseName) { 
        Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination "$dir2\$BaseName"
    }
}
```